# Assigning classes to dynamic content

Tags: css

I have php that is generating content within `<p>` tags. I have two classes that I want to use.

Looks something like:

```
foreach ($record as $r){
   print "<p>" . $r['content'] . "</p>";
}
```

One class is called `readmore`. I want to assign it to anything with an `<a href>`.
The other is called `list01`. I want to assign it to any `<ul>` tags.

Could anyone assist?

Comment: If you want it to be for anything (A and UL element), why not just apply those styles to these elements rather than assigning a class?

Comment: Do you mean all As and all ULs within that P should be styled a certain way?

Comment: @StefanH, yes; all As and ULs within my P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to your paragraph so that you can distinguish it from others, then use this CSS:

```
.myParagraphClass a
{
    /* Your readmore styles go here */
}


.myParagraphClass ul
{
    /* Your list01 styles go here */
}
```

You do not need to target those elements directly with a class since you can target them by the parent child relationship they have to the paragraph

Answer (score 0):

You can use a number of ways to solve this, adding classes would be done in your PHP or after DOM load by Javascript/Jquery.

Using just CSS (and you don't care about ie6) you could:

```
p > a 
{ 
    /* <a> Styles here */
}

p > ul
{
    /* <ul> styles */
}
```

Or maybe target just the last `<a>` in the `<p>`

```
p a:last-child
{
    /* Last child styles */
}
```